# Sendmailconfig conmand with ansible, answer questions

Tags: ansible, config, sendmail

I need exec "sendmailconfig" command in Ansible task and answer yes.

I try it with this code:

```
- name: Exec sendmailconfig
  expect:
    command: sendmailconfig
    responses:
      Question:
        - Configure sendmail with the existing /etc/mail/sendmail.conf? [Y]: y
        - Configure sendmail with the existing /etc/mail/sendmail.mc? [Y]: y
        - Reload the running sendmail now with the new configuration? [Y]: y
    timeout: 30
```

but the task finish with error:

> TASK [Exec sendmailconfig]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************* fatal: [demoHostAnsible]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd":
>   "sendmailconfig", "delta": "0:00:30.133671", "end": "2019-10-04
>   14:55:34.398377", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null,
>   "start": "2019-10-04 14:55:04.264706", "stdout": "Configure sendmail
>   with the existing /etc/mail/sendmail.conf? [Y] ", "stdout_lines":
>   ["Configure sendmail with the existing /etc/mail/sendmail.conf? [Y]
>   "]}

What is the problem? Is there any other way to execute the sendmailconfig command from Ansible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have two, if not three issues in here:

### Mixing syntaxes

The [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) module has two syntaxes, which you mixed.

Either you have to use it, by just providing subsequent responses:

```
responses:
  Questions:
    - response 1
    - response 2
    - response 3
```

Either you have to use it with (question / response) as (key / value) pairs

```
responses:
  question 1: response 1
  question 2: response 2
  question 3: response 3
```

When what you did is:

```
# Author disclaimer, this is a bad syntax!
responses:
  Questions:
    - question 1: response 1
    - question 2: response 2
    - question 3: response 3
```

### The questions provided to `expect` are parsed as regex

If you use the question / response pair, then the question is parsed as a regex. And in your question you have 5 symbols that would need escaping to be considered as literal and not as regex syntax: `/`, `.`, `?`, `[` and `]`.

So your responses have to look like this:

```
responses:
  Configure sendmail with the existing \/etc\/mail\/sendmail\.conf\? \[Y\] : y
  Configure sendmail with the existing \/etc\/mail\/sendmail\.mc\? \[Y\] : y
  Reload the running sendmail now with the new configuration\? \[Y\] : y
```

You can easily identify those kind of issues by throwing your questions in a regex explainer, like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

- It makes it quite easy to see what the parser will consider as token: https://regex101.com/r/vucKjy/1/
- Then you just need to escape them and validate that your question match the regex https://regex101.com/r/uEjrio/1/

### Your timeout is probably too low

Your `timeout` is possibly too low, even set at `60` it was still exceeding the timeout on my docker testing environment, I had to raise it to `120` for it to work.

---

### Two possible ways of approaching the solution

1. Questions / responses as key /value:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Exec sendmailconfig
      expect:
        command: sendmailconfig
        responses:
          Configure sendmail with the existing \/etc\/mail\/sendmail\.conf\? \[Y\] : y
          Configure sendmail with the existing \/etc\/mail\/sendmail\.mc\? \[Y\] : y
          Reload the running sendmail now with the new configuration\? \[Y\] : y
        timeout: 120
```

2. Responses list

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Exec sendmailconfig
      expect:
        command: sendmailconfig
        responses:
          Questions:
            - y
            - y
            - y
        timeout: 120
```

Those two syntaxes both yield me this recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Exec sendmailconfig] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and extensive explanation. I tried both solutions, **the first one worked perfectly for me**. The second continues to offer me the same error.

Comment: @Alex that's odd. The second syntax has been added "later" (in 2.1, which is quite old still). So if your `ansible --version` does not gives you something < 2.1 I don't really see why this won't work for you. But if you are happy with the first one, so am I :)